# What is the recommended way to update PHPMailer?

Tags: installation, phpmailer, updates

I've inherited an unmaintained web server with a custom web application that included PHPMailer 5.2.13.

It seems it was installed using GIT, what would be the recommended way to upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the readme](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) says, the best way to install PHPMailer is with [composer](https://getcomposer.org). That way running `composer update` will get you the latest stable version, whatever that is. PHPMailer does not guarantee that the `master` branch is always usable, but tagged releases are. If you want to update to a stable version manually using git, you can manually check out the git tag associated with the latest named release (currently `v5.2.21`):

```
git fetch
git checkout v5.2.21
```

You need to make sure that your git remote is pointing at the upstream PHPMailer repo (`https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.git`) and not your own clone.

Comment: Thank you, I don't normally deal directly with this kind of updates. Is there a way to make sure the current install was done with composer vs. GIT?

Comment: If your project uses composer, you will have a `composer.json` file and a `vendor` folder in your project root. If git, `git status` will say something positive.